# Perturbations method to solve differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

Hi  I am trying to solve the following differential equation
$ \frac {d^2y }{dt^2}+ \epsilon \frac { dy}{dt}+1=0$
With the conditions  $y (0)=0$ and $dy/dt(t=0)=1$
And what I got is
$y=- \frac {t^2}{2} + \epsilon \frac {t^4}{24} - \epsilon^2 \frac {t^6}{720}+ \dots$  But i am not sure if it is correct or not?

Comment: Following what I think you were doing, $y_0''+1=0 \Rightarrow y_0=-t^2/2$ (plus homogeneous terms that you have neglected completely). Assuming $-t^2/2$ satisfies whatever boundary conditions you want, then $y_1''+y_0'=y_1''-t=0$ so $y_1=t^3/6$. So yeah, you definitely made a mistake.

Comment: Ok Ian thank you so much , and you mean the correct answer is $y=- t^2/2 + € t^3/6 - €^2 t^4/24 +€^3 t^5/60+....$

Answer (score 0):

You can here compute the exact solution and compare your perturbation results against it. Integrating once gives
$$
y'+ϵy+t=y_0'+ϵy_0+0=1
$$
This is still simple enough that the method of undetermined coefficients works,
$$
y(t)=Ae^{-ϵt}+Bt+C\\
B+ϵ(Bt+C)=1-t\implies B=-\frac1ϵ,~C=\frac{1+ϵ}{ϵ^2}, \\
y_0=0\implies~ A=-C
$$
so that finally
$$
y(t)=\frac{(1+ϵ)(1-e^{-ϵt})-ϵt}{ϵ^2}
=t-(1+ϵ)(\tfrac12t^2-\tfrac16ϵt^3+\tfrac1{24}ϵ^2t^4\mp...)\\
=t-\tfrac12t^2-ϵ(\tfrac12t^2-\tfrac16t^3)+ϵ^2(\tfrac16t^3-\tfrac1{24}t^4)\mp...
$$

Comment: Ok but I  still confused about the conditions that are given  ..for example the second tearm $y_{1} =(1/6 t^3 - 1/2 t^2)$ it dose meet just the first condition but not the second $y'(0)=1$   could you please explain?

Comment: The given initial conditions are satisfied with $y_0=t-\tfrac12t^2$. The other $y_k$ have initial conditions equal to zero, as the given initial conditions do not depend on $ϵ$.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for explaining. And is that true for all situation, I mean the initial condition always satisfied with $y_{0}$ only

Comment: Yes, if it does not depend on $ϵ$. It would be different if for example $y(0)=ϵ$ was given, then $y_1(0)=1$.

Comment: Many thanks for you I got it :)